# ggforestplot error: Error in assertAndRetrieveTidyValue(x, mean) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to create a forest plot using `ggforestplot`, but am receiving the error message:

> Error in assertAndRetrieveTidyValue(x, mean) :
> argument "x" is missing, with no default

```
library(ggforestplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df_linear <-
  df_linear_associations %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name) %>%
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() <= 30)

# Forestplot
forestplot(
  df = df_linear,
  estimate = beta,
  logodds = FALSE,
  colour = trait,
  xlab = "1-SD increment in cardiometabolic trait
  per 1-SD increment in biomarker concentration"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Ilari Scheinin said complete right, this error happens when you have loaded the `forestplot` package and use the `forestplot` function. In the following reproducible code you can see that the error happens when doing that:

```r
library(forestplot)
library(ggforestplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df_linear <-
  df_linear_associations %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name) %>%
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() <= 30)

# Forestplot
forestplot::forestplot(
  df = df_linear,
  estimate = beta,
  logodds = FALSE,
  colour = trait,
  xlab = "1-SD increment in cardiometabolic trait
  per 1-SD increment in biomarker concentration"
)
#> Error in assertAndRetrieveTidyValue(x, mean): argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Make sure to unloaded the forestplot!**

Code when not loaded `forestplot`:

When I run your code, there is no error. Maybe try restarting your environment and clean and try again. Here is the reproducible code:

```r
library(ggforestplot)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

df_linear <-
  df_linear_associations %>%
  dplyr::arrange(name) %>%
  dplyr::filter(dplyr::row_number() <= 30)

# Forestplot
forestplot(
  df = df_linear,
  estimate = beta,
  logodds = FALSE,
  colour = trait,
  xlab = "1-SD increment in cardiometabolic trait
  per 1-SD increment in biomarker concentration"
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Many thanks for the response. I have tried restarting/ cleaning the environment and still receive the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @DavidDearlove Maybe try reinstalling ggforestplot with install_github?

Comment: The code above works for me too. It looks like the error comes from another package called `forestplot`, so I guess you have loaded not only `ggforestplot` but `forestplot` as well. If you change the function call `forestplot()` to an explicit `ggforestplot::forestplot()`, it will call the right function and I'd imagine should work.

Comment: @IlariScheinin, You are right! I added a reproducible example when loading the `forestplot` library and running the function with that package!

Comment: @quinten thanks for the response. I think the issue was I had the forestplot() and ggforestplot() packages simultaneously loaded. Maybe there is syntax crossover?!

Comment: Sorry - just read the comments above - you beat me to it. Thanks you both. I very much appreciate your help. David